# Never ending loop while setting focus to control on validating event in cantrol validating event

Tags: vb.net, validation

I am writing below code for validating compulsary field account no. in form.
User's requirement is set focus back on field when error comes :

```
If txtAccountNo = "" Then

    MessageBox.Show("Account no filed can't be left empty")
    txtAccountNo.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

End If
```

It's working properlly. But suppose user don't want to fill form and exiting from aaplication.
Message box keep on appearing till user enters account no.

How can I avoid this situation?
Please help.

Comment: Set Option Strict On in your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to indicate user has seen messagebox. Check the flag to prevent any future messagebox. Make sure the flag is set *before* setting focus back to textbox e.g.

```
dim bMsgBox as boolean=false

If txtAccountNo = "" and bMsgBox = false Then

    MessageBox.Show("Account no filed can't be left empty")
    bMsgBox=true
    txtAccountNo.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the validation rules in one function / procedure / subrutine (I'm not familiar with VB, mostly C++ / C# user). Then call this function only when user is committing the data filled in, and set focus to first control with mandatory data not filled or invalid data entered.

Say you have a form with 3 controls to be filled in:

- a date control not mandatory - dteDate
- a text box mandatory - txtAccoutInfo
- a text box mandatory - txtAddress

and 2 buttons:

- button Save and button Cancel.

When 'Save' button is pressed you first call the function / procedure to validate user input. If date entered is invalid in dteDate, you set focus on it and return / exit the function; if no text is entered in txtAccountInfo then set focus on it and return / exit the function; if no text is entered in txtAddress then set focus on it and return / exit.

When 'Cancel' is pressed you don't call this function, but just quit.